# How to use graph api v2.0 with PHP SDK anymore

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an `PHP` script with `fql_query` and for some days it's giving following error :

```
rest api is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher
```

So, I want to use `Graph SDK v2.0` But i don't know how to use it. I read somewhere that we need to use V2.0 somewhere on script to do that.

Can anyone please help me solve the issue. It'll be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is, as opposed to asking `('/me')` make a request for `('/v2.0/me')` by specifying the version number before the call.

See "making versioned requests" on this page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.1#versions

But you also need to note that if you App was created AFTER 2.1 was released, then you can't go backwards and use 2.0; you can only use 2.0 if you app was created before 2.1 was released; and then you only have 2 years to update it to be 2.1 compliant.

Comment: Per your link, you actually need to place `/v2.0/me` rather than `/2.0/me` (note the v)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using the endpoint `https://api.facebook.com/`, instead of using `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={your_fql_query}&access_token={access_token}` as outlined at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#example

If your app is a Graph API v2.1 app, you won't be able to use FQl anymore. If it's a Graph API v2.0 app, you'll be able to use FQL until April 30th 2016.

Comment: keep in mind that fql is not available anymore in v2.1

Comment: I know, but he's writing explicitly "v2.0" in the title, so I assume his app can actually use FQL. It will vanish on April 30th 2016, for sure.